# Why does stall speed decrease when flaps are deployed?

Tags: aerodynamics, flaps, stall, angle-of-attack

I've been told that deploying the flaps on approach enables the following:

1. Potentially steeper approach
2. Slows down the plane
3. Lower stall speed

It's the last one that confuses me.

---

Given the equation for lift:

$ L = \frac{1}{2}C_l  ρ V^2 S$

with:

- $L$ - lift
- $C_l$- lift coefficient
- $\rho$ - density of the air
- $V$ - velocity
- $S$ - surface area of the wing

---

When we deploy the flaps, we automatically change the camber of the wing which does the following:

1. Increases the surface area of the wing
2. Increases our current angle of attack

As a result of the change in surface area of the wing, we can decrease our *V* in the equation and generate the same amount of lift that was needed before flaps. Does that sound correct?

For most practical purposes, your average GA pilot doesn't deal with the *AOA* because it can't be readily calculated so the POH typically lists the stall speed *Vs*. However, as I understand it, stall speed is indirectly correlated with our plane's "critical angle of attack".

What I don't quite understand is, **why exactly does our stall speed decrease when we deploy the flaps?**

Is it because of what I outlined earlier, that we can produce an equivalent amount of lift at a lower speed because of the change in wing surface area?

Comment: If they *didn't* decrease stall speed, why bother having them? Points #1 and #2 can be achieved with flat-plate speed brakes.

Comment: I'm not sure I take your point? I'm not debating the fact that they decrease stall speed, I'm asking how it occurs.

Comment: Do you mind marking one of the provided answers? I am curious (and I think others as well) of what have helped you -if anything did- to understand.

Comment: @SteliosAdamantidis To be honest, that's one of the reasons I haven't marked an answer yet - they're both extremely helpful so I'm having trouble choosing between them. After rereading them again, I went ahead and marked an answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your stall speed decreases because the $C_{L_{MAX}}$ of the wing increases with flaps deflected.

Deploying flaps increases wing camber and increases both $C_L$ and $C_D$ at the same AoA and airspeed. Depending on the type of flap, the critical AoA actually reduces: the airfoil with simple flaps deflected stalls at a lower AoA than without flaps.

[image: From a rediscovered lecture book, decades old and paper copy only]

Slats or leading edge flaps do not change the $C_L$ at the same AoA, but allow for a higher AoA and therefore higher $C_L$ before the airfoil stalls.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

The flaps mostly increase the camber, which increases the C<sub>l</sub> (albeit, with greater drag).

In quite a few cases (especially low-end GA aircraft) the flaps have little or no effect on the wing's surface area (the flaps are just a section of the trailing edge that swings downward on a hinge).

[image]

Even in those that do slide the flaps back on a track, the change in surface area is quite small compared to the change in camber (and with it, C<sub>l</sub>).

[image]

Comment: To be explicit (and answer the question), the increase of $C_L$ provided by flaps extension allows to produce the same lift amount with a reduced speed for the same AOA, hence just before reaching the critical AOA, the aircraft can fly level at a lower speed.